# Don't Want Include Tag's Stylesheet to Mix With Current Page's

Tags: html, css, pug

I have an include tag in dashboard.jade to include my header.jade file, but the header.jade file has its own stylesheet and when I run it, dashboard.jade's stylesheet also applies to the included header.jade. Is there a way to have dashboard.jade's stylesheet to apply only to it and not the included header.jade?

Here's my code for dashboard.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Todo List
    |    &#x9;
    |     
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='assets/css/todos.css')
    |    &#x9;
    |     
    link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    |    &#x9;
    |     
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href=' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css')
    |    &#x9;
    |     
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lemonade/2.1.0/lemonade.min.css')
    |    &#x9;
    |     
    script(type='text/javascript', src='assets/plugins/jquery-3.0.0.min.js')
  |    
  |   
  body
    include partials/header
```

And here's my code for header.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Eisenhower Productivity Tool
    // Meta
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    |     
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    |     
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    |     
    meta(name='description', content='')
    |     
    meta(name='author', content='')
    |     
    |     
    link(rel='shortcut icon', href='../favicon.ico')
    |   
    |     
    link(href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    // Global CSS
    link(href='../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    // Plugins CSS
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='../assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')
    // Theme CSS
    link#theme-style(rel='stylesheet', href='assets/css/styles.css')
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a layout based environment, extending a default theme with block statements? You can use vars for each page to check them against conditions.

Comment: @Daniel Do you mean as in `extends layout`? Because I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work so well for me. Thanks for taking your time to help!

Comment: If what you're referring to is `extends "some layout"` how would you use the vars to check them against conditions? I know that might be a very ignorant question, but still.

Comment: Iam still at work, i can write an example later when I'm at home. Iam using Layout based environment almost always. Guess this fit's for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use different CSS-Stylesheets I recommend to use a layoutbased enviroment with typical Jade/Pug `block` statements.

This is how a layoutbased folder structur can look like:

```
|--./
|-- |--jade
|-- |-- |-- layouts
|-- |-- |-- |-- mylayout.jade
|-- |-- |-- template_1.jade
|-- |-- |-- template_2.jade
```

This could be your layout file `mylayout.jade`:

```
doctype html

block vars
  // Some default variables

html

  head
    block head
      // default head for title and meta

    block defaultCSS
      // default css
      link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='path/to/default_style.css')
      style.
        body {}

   block additionalCSS

  body
    block body
      // default html in body
    block footer

  block defaultJS
    script.
      var someDefaltJavaScript = 'awsome"
```

**And here the template files**

`template_1.jade`:

```
extends layout/mylayout.pug

block head
  // this overrides the default "block head" from the layout
  // So put your special meta for your page here

block additionalCSS
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='path/to/other_style.css')

block body
  .this
    .is
      #where
       .your.content.goes
```

`template_2.jade`:

```
extends layout/mylayout.pug

block head
  // this overrides the default "block head" from the layout
  // So put your special meta for your page here

//- We dont use the "block additionalCSS" because we dont need it in this template

block body
  .this
    .is
      #where
       .your.content.goes
```

Beware to compile only the templatefiles, here is some other example: http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/.

You can also take a look into this small jade app of mine on github: h[ttps://github.com/pure180/gulp-pug-inheritance-test/tree/master/app](https://github.com/pure180/gulp-pug-inheritance-test/tree/master/app)